# Python pickling objects and conatiners of objects within those objects

Tags: python, object, pickle

Hey guys so I have a program set up and almost working, but I have come across this problem where when you pickle an object from a container, it only saves the top most layer, while my structure is a little more specific.... it goes like this.

OuterClass->Acts a container for people objects (has an array that contains people)

PeopleClass -> Make order objects, which are then contained within the people as "current orders" "completed orders"

OrderClass -> A template for a generic order for my wife's business, has a dictionaries(product and quantity) and some integers (pricing stuff) inside

I have obviously tried doing multiple dumps into one file, but this of course only saves the top object of each structure while. So without slugging tons of time into some sort of hacked together unintuitive dump counter, I figured I would reach out and see if there is a good strategy for this.

```py
    class Person:
        name = ""
        currentOrders = []
        def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def placeOrder(self, Order):
        if len(self.currentOrders) > 0:
            print(self.name + " has unpaid orders!")

        self.currentOrders.append(Order)
        print("Order attached")

     def toString(self):
        print("Technician Name: ", self.name)
        print("\nCurrent orders:")
        print("-----------")
        for order in self.currentOrders:
            order.toString()
   
    class Order:
        date = None
        items = {}

        def __init__(self, items):
            for size in items:
                self.items[size] = items[size]
                self.date = datetime.now()

        def toString(self):
            # print("Date:", self.date)
            print("-------Item-------")
            for item in self.items:
                print("Type: " + item)
                print("items: " + str(self.items[item][0]))
                print("Price per item: " + str(self.items[item][1]))
                print("-------------------")
     
    class PeronContainer(object):

        currentTechs = []

        def addTech(self, tech)
            self.currentTechs.append(tech)
    
        def save_objects(self):
            for tech in self.currentTechs:
                with open(tech.name + ".pkl", 'wb') as output:  # Overwrites any 
                                                            existing file.
                pickle.dump(tech, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
                pickle.dump(tech.currentOrders, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    
        def load_objects(self):
            file_names = []

            for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled4"):
                if file.endswith(".pkl"):
                    file_names.append(file)
            for filename in file_names:
                with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                    tech = pickle.load(f)
                    tech.currentOrders = pickle.load(f)
                    self.addTech(tech)
        
        def toString():
            for tech in currentTechs:
                 tech.toString()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Me = Person.Person("Jeremy")
    Me.placeOrder(classOrder.Order({"Thing": (5, 7.40)}, 5.00, 3.00))
    Me.placeOrder(classOrder.Order({"Thing2": (15, 7.50)}, 10, 5))
   
    execution = PersonContainer()
    execution.addTech(Me)
    execution.toString()
    execution.save_objects()
```

```
###This will output:
```

Order attached
Me has unpaid orders!
Order attached
Technician Name:  Me

Current orders:

### -------Item-------
Type: Thing1
Trays: 5
Price per tray: 7.4

### Type: Thing2
Trays: 15
Price per tray: 7.5

### this is an order view

### -------Item-------
Type: Thing1
Trays: 5
Price per tray: 7.4

### Type: Thing2
Trays: 15
Price per tray: 7.5

```
    execute = LashTracking()


    execute.load_objects()
    execute.toString()
```

Technician Name:  Jeremy

### Current orders:

Date: None
-------Item-------
Date: None
-------Item-------

Process finished with exit code 0

As we can see, only the top layer is recognized in savingThank you muchly in advance

Comment: "but I have come across this problem where when you pickle an object from a container, it only saves the top most layer," It shouldn't be behaving that way. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: If you are allowed to use external modules I suggest taking look at [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) which does extends `pickle` providing pickle-like interface. Though I am not sure how it would fare against your custom classes.